# How to make an add-on for mIRC or any other IRC client that alarms you when a certain string is mentioned in a chat room?

Tags: irc, add-on, mirc

It'd be quite useful to me to have an add-on that alerts me when something specific is said in a chat room, same way you're warned if your nick is mentioned, just for a string you'd like.

How would one go about doing this? Is there an interface for IRC programming, what NetBeans is to Java for example.

I'm not sure how I would even approach IRC programming, so forgive me if my assumptions are just dead wrong.

Comment: This is possible with pretty much every client that supports scripting (mIRC, irssi, WeeChat, X-Chat etc..). First decide on which client you want to use, then ask specifically for that client.

Comment: This is a configuration question (most irc clients use a config for this), too broad (every answer for a IRC Client is correct).

Answer (score 1):

As the guy at the comment said, first choose IRC Client that support "scripting" or has a built in function to alert.
Then look for the solution.

**Code in case of mIRC**

```
on *:text:*someword*:#channel: {
  echo -ag Alert
  beep 3
}
```

The code should go to the "Remote" window (alt+r)